# Factoring higher-order ODEs

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, factoring

I have been researching various methods for solving differential equations.  In particular, I want to better understand the factoring approach.  For example, if we want to solve a general second order linear ODE of the form
$$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y = 0,$$
We can propse the factorization
$$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y = (D+\phi_1(x))((D+\phi_2(x))y = 0.$$
It turns out that one can find $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ by solving an associated Ricatti equation.  Then, the original problem may be solved by first solving
$$(D+\phi_1(x))Y = 0,$$
and then
$$(D+\phi_2(x))y = Y.$$

My question is if this can be extended to higher orders, for example factorizing
$$y'''+p(x)y''+q(x)y'+r(x)y = (D+\phi_1)(D+\phi_2)(D+\phi_3)y = 0.$$
If we attempt a similar approach as with the second-order equation, we will arrive at a nonlinear first-order system for $\phi_{1,2,3}$.  If curious if there are smart methods for factoring that avoid complicated nonlinear equations.

Comment: For the second order case, (and I’d wager my life savings this is the same for the third order case), the ‘associated Ricatti equation’ is equivalent to the original second order ODE. Take $\phi_1(x)=u’/u$ and you’ll find $y=u$. This is a recurring theme of 2nd order linear ODEs where to solve it you must know a particular solution to it.

Comment: It is just as Eli said. For this reason, the factorizarion method is only useful in a very limited set of circumstances.